# Fantom cannot approve spending USDC token

Tags: gas, fees, erc-20-approve, usdc, fantom

I am doing simple approve operation on USDC token in Fantom network.

Here is my payload:

```
functionParams {
  from: '0xd775b00b5cf6e954aed8408202367a1bae6ac55f',
  to: '0x04068da6c83afcfa0e13ba15a6696662335d5b75',
  data: '0x095ea7b3000000000000000000000000af5191b0de278c7286d6c7cc6ab6bb8a73ba2cd6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000094314a',
  value: '0x0', 
  gasLimit: 21596, // get via web3.eth.estimateGas(functionParams);
  gasPrice: '50359158882' // get via web3.eth.getGasPrice();
}
```

`ERROR Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

There is ~9 USDC on wallet and ~1.14 FTM.

In comparison with other networks it took around 0.01$ for approve transaction, so I assume I have enough tokens for this transaction.

What is wrong then?

Please help.

P.S. Tried [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144371/failing-to-trying-to-approve-contract-using-ethers-js-call-exception-or-cannot) answer did not help

Comment: I changed RPC and it worked, basically went to [chainlist](https://chainlist.org/chain/250) and got trustful RPC from there instead of quicknode, which did not work at all.....
(they say it custom and should work better than public, yeah yeah)